# Git doesn't ask me for username and password after pushing, but I am pushing to another remote

Tags: git

I have been pushing to a public repo for a long time, everytime when I do `git push`, I didn't have to enter username/password, the pushing process just happened instantly when I hit Enter.

Today I want to push my project to my private repo, after adding my private repo to my remote using `git remote add private <url>`,I tried `git push` but a fatal error came out and said "authentication failed, invalid username or password".

I mean, I couldn't even enter my username or password, so the username or password I have right now is probably for my public repo. So how do I make git to let me enter username and password again?

Comment: what is the scheme of your remote?

Comment: @DanFarrell I'm sorry for being a noob, but what does scheme mean?

Comment: @L.Z. The first portion of the URL, prior to the domain (e.g. `https://` or `git:`)

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov I tried both HTTPS and SSH, neither worked. I just didn't have username/pw prompt.

Comment: That response would probably be better directed at @DanFarrell as a response to his comment; I'm not as familiar with Git as he might be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably enabled Git Credential Manager when you installed git or the first time you pushed to a repo. Git Credential Manager caches and re-uses credentials between different push commands, so it could be re-using credentials for a different remote. Without credential manager, you would have to type in your credentials on every push.

Please follow the advice in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git) to clear your credentials. Note the 2nd answer is specific to Windows Devices, whereas the first should work for MacOS and Linux.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem like magic. Removing the credential from the vault did prompt me password entry for me.